# Git or Github pull, push errors solution in Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gitlab, android-studio-bumblebee

```
git config credential.helper store
```

Enable "Use Credential Helper" in Settings -> Version Control -> Git.

In Every project you have to config with this terminal code.

*This is a temporary solution until find anything related to this issue

Comment: I got the solution of this problem, the answer is :

git config --global credential.helper store

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error:- "Push failed, Invocation failed Unexpected end of file from server"

Enter This command in terminal/CMD

```
git config --local user.name 'your username'
git config --local user.password 'your password'
git config --global credential.helper store
```

Solution:- Also make sure, "Use Credential help" is checked in setting > VCS > Git.
[Android Setting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1HK1.png)

Answer (score 2):

> In Every project you have to config with this terminal code.

If you want to configure it for every project in one go:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

Note that the Microsoft GCM ([Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager)) would be more secure than 'store" (which stores credentials in plain text).
You can [install GCM](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager#download-and-install) on Windows/Linux/Mac (it comes by default with [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases))

Comment: @MubarakAnsariYou are most welcome.

Comment: @MubarakAnsari Wait, wasn't this answer accepted? What is missing from it?